# Substrate node template error#E0463 - can't find crate for std

Tags: substrate

I am following the tutorial [importing contracts pallet crate]. Installed nightly-2020-10-06 and cargo build. When I run code get error - "cant find std"_"the wasm32-unknown-unknown target may not be installed". Can not work out where I am going wrong... Have added [dependencies] and [features] runtime code - then ran cargo check... where I get error... Would like to know where I am going wrong, and how too solve issue..

Answer (score 2):

depending on the toolchain you're building with you can write

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

or

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-10-06
```

and specify the toolchain with a `+<toolchain>` in your cargo commands like `cargo +nightly build`

Comment: I installed [rustup nightly-2020-10-06] and used your second example (above) – specified [cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build] – cargo builds successfully!...When I run [cargo check],  I get an error ‘error[E0282]: type annotations needed’ . Appreciated your advice!

Comment: I now got error[E0282]: type annotations needed - when I run [cargo check]..

Comment: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Comment: what's your output if you do a `$ cargo -V` in that folder? there might be a `rust-toolchain` file in the repo that interferes with it. 
also, you wrote `cargo check` without specifying the toolchain in the command. was that actually the case or did you just miss to include it in the comment?

Comment: Do I need to install a different nightly?

Comment: In addition, did you provide the `-b v2.0.0` flag when cloning the node-template? After similar problems to yours, I omitted that and things worked nicely. the `-b v2.0.0` flag might fail on the latest `nightly` rust...

Comment: Thanks for your re[ply...How do I provide the -  -b v2.0.0 flag?...

Comment: You may be encountering this problem https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/90#issuecomment-706041447

Comment: I mean you should _not_ provide it ;-)
I was assuming that you had cloned the substrate-node-template as mentioned in the tutorial where there is a `-b v2.0.0` flag in the `git clone` command. I omitted that and then I didn't have any compilation errors with rust nightly